# Using RayCastAll instead of RayCast

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two gameobjects roller and marker. When I use physics raycast it works, but with raycastall it doesn't. I need to use raycastall, because i need to iterate through colliders. When marker is on roller normal raycast doesn't work and I need to use raycastall.

This code works:

```c#
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    // get mouse position in screen space
    // (if touch, gets average of all touches)
    Vector3 screenPos = Input.mousePosition;
    // set a distance from the camera
    screenPos.z = 10.0f;
    // convert mouse position to world space
    Ray cameraRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    Physics.Raycast(cameraRay, out hit);
    if (hit.collider.tag == "Floor")
    {
        transform.position = hit.point;
    }

    /*
    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos);
    // get current position of this GameObject
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    // set x position to mouse world-space x position
    newPos.x = worldPos.x;
    newPos.z = worldPos.z-3f;
    // apply new position
    transform.position = newPos;
    */

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        touchhandler = GameObject.Find("Roller").GetComponent<TouchHandler>();
        touchhandler.markerexists = false;
    }
}
```

And this doesn't:

```c#
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    // get mouse position in screen space
    // (if touch, gets average of all touches)
    Vector3 screenPos = Input.mousePosition;
    // set a distance from the camera
    screenPos.z = 10.0f;
    // convert mouse position to world space
    Ray cameraRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit[] hits;
    hits = Physics.RaycastAll(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), 100.0F);
    while (i < hits.Length)
    {
        RaycastHit hit = hits[i];
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Floor") 
        {
            transform.position = hit.point;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        touchhandler = GameObject.Find("Roller").GetComponent<TouchHandler>();
        touchhandler.markerexists = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So why do you pass `100.0F` to `RaycastAll`?

Comment: max distance of ray

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use a `foreach` loop for iterating over the `hits` instead of that `while`! `foreach(var hit in hits){ if (hit.collider.tag == "Floor") { transform.position = hit.point; } }` also you have to decide: do you want the latest hit or the first? In later case you also would want to add a `break;` after the assigning of `transform.position` .. a hard desicion having in mind that **`Note that order is not guaranteed.`** ([Physics.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html)) -> You could as well stick to `Physics.Raycast` ...